# Specify current item in DataContext directly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This seems like a pretty standard question but I can't seem to find any answer. How do I bind to the current object in the datacontext (i.e. `this`).

To give a simplified example:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfFoos}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <!-- How do I specify a Foo item directly here 
                 and not just one of its properties? -->
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding this}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I tried `this` or `.` but to no avail. Obviously there's a simple hack of just creating a pseudo property in the Foo class ala:

```
public Foo Self { get { return this;  } }
```

which then allows me to just use `{Binding Self}`, but I'm sure there must be a better way to  achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can put *nothing* to refer to current `DataContext` :

```
Bar="{Binding}"
```

Or if you want to use `.`, put it as the value of `Path` property of `Binding` :

```
Bar="{Binding Path=.}"
```